# No connectivity in LAN (arp table does not learn IP addresses)

Tags: windows, subnet, nic, route, arp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIPPJ.jpg)I have a server connected with NICs as follows,

1. 10.0.11.11/24 - no gateway required.
2. 10.0.10.11/24 - with gateway 10.0.10.240
3. 192.168.2.11/24 - no gateway required.

When I assign IP address to an unused NIC as 192.168.1.x/24, and try connecting relevant LAN, no IP can be reached. Ping itself is successful. Arp cash has learnt none. Also when pinging to a relevant IP, server first try to send it via relevant NIC and then via default gateway.

Routing table of the server is attached in the picture.

But when I assign IP address to same NIC in 172.16.1.x/24 and try connecting relevant LAN it is successful.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC9MB.jpg)

Can somebody let me know what the problem is?
the routing of the server is in the attached pic.

Comment: You say "no IP can be reached", but that the "ping itself is successful", can you expand on that?

Comment: Ping to the NIC IP replies. But for others e.g. there were PCs of IP 192.168.1.7 etc. can not ping and also none of this range were in arp cache. Except broadcast address of this network.

Comment: What type of network adapter? What operating system?

Comment: It is an HPE Ethernet 1Gb 4 Port 331T Adapter. OS is Windows Server 2019.

Comment: Might there be a policy in firewall to block this IP range? I can check it tomorrow.

Comment: Please provide your current routing table and an traceroute to an ip or network you want to reach

Comment: Hi Turdie, it is in the attached pic.

Comment: Hi Turdie, I added tracert result and arp -a result. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have multiple network adapters you probably need to update the routing table.
An so called static route.

The gateway defined probably knowns the network route to 172.16.1.x/24, but not to the 192.168.' network

Comment: Hi, I added a static route as route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.34.  But the result is the same. I will share you tracert result soon.